# i want to store some vars in a dll

Tags: c++, dll

i'm programming a dll in c++ to use it with another languages.

The problem is that i don't know if the dll can store some data in structs to use in differents calls of a unique execution.

For example,

1. The dll create three sockets when the executable program call the initializing function.
2. In the same execution (without close the exe program or open another instance of it) the exe calls to send a message by a socket.

Could the dll store the socket id and after access to it in this execution?

Thanks everyone and sorry for my English, i'm improving it.

Comment: Your DLL should store its data in some "context" structure that it allocates during some "initialization" or "create" call.  This context should be passed to the DLL for all future calls. It can be an [opaque type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use global static variables or file scope variables in your CPP files.

In a Windows C++ DLL, all global objects (including static members of classes) will be constructed just before the calling of the DllMain with DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, and they will be destroyed just after the call of the DllMain with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.